# Display "Key has been used" if key has already been used

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a system where a user is given a promo-code and they enter it into a form. The system checks if the code has been used and if it has not it returns with "Code has been used". If it has not it returns with the product key.

So far I got it to message if the code is invalid, and if the key is correct and not used but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to echo a message if the promo code has already been used.

The "acode" is the access code.

The "akey" is what is returned if it is valid and unused.

[The database setup here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Q5p.png)

```
<form method="POST">
    Access Code:
    <input type="text" name="acode">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="sub">
</form>

    <?php 
        // this will trigger when submit button click
        if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
            $db = new mysqli("","","","");
            // create query
            $query = "SELECT * FROM promo_codes WHERE acodes='".$_POST['acode']."'";

            // execute query
            $sql = $db->query($query);
            // num_rows will count the affected rows base on your sql query. so $n will return a number base on your query
            $n = $sql->num_rows;

            // if $n is > 0 it means there is an existing record that matches base on your query above.

            if($n > 0){
                $coderesult  = "SELECT akeys FROM promo_codes WHERE isclaimed='0' AND acodes='".$_POST['acode']."' LIMIT 1";
                $results = $db->query($coderesult);
                    foreach($results as $row)
                        {
                            if ($n > 0){
                                echo "Your key is ".$row['akeys']."<br>";

                            }

                        }
            } else {
                echo "Incorrect Access Key";
            }
        }

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: if it has not it returns with "Code has been used"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly retrieving an `akeys` record. You need to do a `fetch_assoc()` call before actually getting a record from the result object.

**Change:**

```
$results = $db->query($coderesult);
                foreach($results as $row)
                    {
                        if ($n > 0){
                            echo "Your key is ".$row['akeys']."<br>";

                        }

                    }
```

**To:**

```
$results = $db->query($coderesult);
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();

if(isset($row['akeys'])){
    echo "Your key is ".$row['akeys']."<br>\n";
}
else {
    echo "Code has been used!<br/>\n"
}
```

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Wow thank you! Works great, Thanks for the help. Just starting to dive into php again and am VERY rusty :P

Comment: Glad to help! :D

Comment: I would have thank'd you as well but I did not have enough rep apparently. Thank you!